# Show concatenated values in SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2, listagg

I want to join my first sql query with table Types showed below by id_pr value.ID_PR values are repeated. I want to show all values from ident_st column concatenated with comma separator for same id_pr and rodz_st values. For example: Show all ident_st values for rodz_st='DZE' and id_pr=13.

first query:

```
SELECT NAME, NO FROM ORDERS o
LEFT JOIN TYPES t ON t.ID_ZM = o.ID_PR
```

table Orders:

```
  ID        ID_ZM NAME    NO  
---------- ---------- ------- --------
    1        12   Dee     333
    2        13   Rods    111
```

table Types:

```
ID    ID_PR  RODZ_ST   IDENT_ST   
---------- ---------- ------- --------
16    12      JEW     646101_1
10    12      JEW     236496_2
11    13      JEW     147301_5
15    13      DZE     259435_1
12    13      OBR     452171_3
13    13      OBR     286432_6
17    12      DZE     618054_1
19    13      DZE     182235_4
```

I want result like below:

```
NAME    NO      JEW               DZE                  OBR
------- -----  ---------------- ------------------  -----------------
Dee     333   646101_1, 236496_2 618054_1
Rods    111   147301_5           259435_1, 182235_4 452171_3, 286432_6
```

**Question: How to create sql join with concatenated statement to get showed result?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use list `LISTAGG` function with `DECODE` :

```
SELECT NAME, NO, 
       LISTAGG(DECODE(RODZ_ST,'JEW',IDENT_ST,NULL), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.ID DESC, RODZ_ST) AS JEWS,
       LISTAGG(DECODE(RODZ_ST,'DZE',IDENT_ST,NULL), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.ID , RODZ_ST) AS DZE,
       LISTAGG(DECODE(RODZ_ST,'OBR',IDENT_ST,NULL), ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.ID , RODZ_ST) AS OBR
  FROM ORDERS o
   LEFT JOIN TYPES t ON t.ID_PR = o.ID_ZM
  GROUP BY NAME, NO;
```

[*SQL Fiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8699/13)

Comment: @KhanM i've added a Demo